# How to re-write multiple normal join statements into multiple INNER JOIN statements?

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is the SQL query with multiple joins as shown below:

```
SELECT H1.horse_name AS Horse, H2.horse_name AS Sire, event_name AS Event
FROM Horse AS H1, Horse AS H2, Event, Entry, Entry AS SireEntry
WHERE H1.horse_sire = H2.horse_id
AND H1.horse_id = Entry.horse_id
AND H2.horse_id = SireEntry.horse_id
AND Event.event_id = Entry.event_id
AND Event.event_id = SireEntry.event_id;
```

The same SQL statement I was trying to rewrite with multiple INNER JOINS instead of normal joins. But I was not able to get the same result as I got with normal joins.
This was my attempt:

```
SELECT H1.horse_name AS Horse, H2.horse_name AS Sire, event_name AS Event
FROM ((((Horse AS H1 INNER JOIN Horse AS H2 ON H1.horse_sire = H2.horse_id)
INNER JOIN Entry ON H1.horse_id = Entry.horse_id)
INNER JOIN Entry AS SireEntry ON H2.horse_id = SireEntry.horse_id)
INNER JOIN Event ON Event.event_id = SireEntry.event_id);
```

So how do I rewrite the same SQL query syntax with multiple INNER JOINS to get the same result as I got with the normal joins ?
It would be helpful if the syntax is provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot one condition when joining with `Event`:

```
...
INNER JOIN Entry AS SireEntry ON H2.horse_id = SireEntry.horse_id)
INNER JOIN Event ON Event.event_id = SireEntry.event_id 
                AND Event.event_id = Entry.event_id);
```

Comment: Now that you have mentioned it. I have added Event.event_id = Entry.event_id and it worked.